# Replace an object that is inside of array if object id value from another array match

Tags: javascript, arrays, typescript

I have this arrays with objects that looks like this:

```
array1 = [
 0:{id:145, value:130000},
 1:{id:146, value:103300},
 2:{id:147, value:79500},
]

array2 = [
 0:{id:145, value:135000}
]
```

And I want to replace the object inside the array if the id of the object in `array2` match with some id of the object in `array1`

So I expect something like this:

```
array1 = [
 0:{id:145, value:135000},
 1:{id:146, value:103300},
 2:{id:147, value:79500},
]
```

I have this code

```
array1.splice(1, 1, array2[0])
```

but it returns me this:

```
array1 = [
 0:{id:145, value:135000},
 1:{id:145, value:130000},
 2:{id:146, value:103300},
 3:{id:147, value:79500},
]
```

Any help I'll appreciate

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
let array1 = [
 {id:145, value:130000},
 {id:146, value:103300},
 {id:147, value:79500},
]

let array2 = [
 {id:145, value:135000},
 {id:147, value:135023}
]
    array2.map(x => {
    let index = array1.findIndex(d=> d.id === x.id)
  array1[index] = x  
})
console.log(array1)
```

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding how and/or why it solves the problem would improve the answer's long-term value. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer . Good luck 

Answer (score 1):

```
array2.forEach(i1 => {
    const index = array1.findIndex(i2 => i2.id == i1.id);
    if(index > -1) {
        array1.splice(index, 1, i1);
  }
});
```

Comment: Can you explain *why* this works?

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding how and/or why it solves the problem would improve the answer's long-term value. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer . Good luck 

Comment: thanks for answer, both answer help me, thanks!